# Prove cardinals equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $x,c$ two cardinals, such that:
$1\lt x \le c$
$c^2 = c$

Prove:
$x^c = 2^c$

So, from the second statement, we know $c$ is infinite, because it cannot be true for a finite cardinal.

I know the "tools" to prove it must be:

1. CBS theorem
2. cardinals arithmatic
3. squeezing theorem

I tried playing with these, but all I got is bunch of inequalities didn't lead to the answer.

**EDIT**:
What I did so far:
$$\begin{array}{l}x \le b\\{2^x} \le {2^b}\\{\left( {{2^x}} \right)^b} \le {\left( {{2^b}} \right)^b}\\{2^{xb}} \le {2^{bb}}\end{array}$$

I'm pretty much stuck at this point.

Comment: Do you assume axiom of choice? In any case, you can assume without loss of generality that $x=c$.

Comment: $c$ can be 0 or 1.

Comment: @CarlLove: Really? Can $0$ or $1$ be not smaller than a number strictly greater than $1$?

Comment: Oops. Missed that.

Comment: @tomasz: But the axiom of choice is not needed for this result.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm not saying that it's needed, just asking whether or not OP assumes it. :) I think that when you don't assume choice, you should spell it out (though the assumption of $c^2=c$ and mention of CBS certainly do suggest that).

Comment: btw, what is OP initials?

Comment: @tomasz: Many courses of that level don't even mention the axiom of choice, so the OP might not even be aware of it as a possible assumption.

Comment: @AndrePoole: Original Poster. You, in this case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Maybe you're right... I think I had had axiom of choice used explicitly in analysis an linear algebra before this kind of cardinal arithmetic was being introduced, but my recollections of the first year are not exactly very reliable when it comes to chronology. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Remember the laws of exponentiation:

1. $a\leq b\implies 2^a\leq 2^b$.
2. $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.

---

To the edit:

**HINT:** Show that if $x\leq c=c^2\implies xc=c$.

Comment: can you refer to my edit please?

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy to find an injection from ${}^c2$ to ${}^cx$; the hard part is finding one from ${}^cx$ to ${}^c2$. You also have an easy injection from ${}^cx$ to ${}^cc$, so all you really need is an injection from ${}^cc$ to ${}^c2$:

$${}^cc\to{}^c({}^c2)\to{}^{c\times c}2\to{}^c2$$